# what does perl use Cwd qw(); mean?

Tags: perl

What does

```
use Cwd qw();
```

mean in perl?

I know qw gives quotes to each elements inside ()
But what about this case?

Comment: It's a good idea to always list your imports explicitly. That way, it's easy to find out where a sub is defined. In this case, the person went a step further and used the full name of the function (e.g. `Cwd::abs_path`) rather than importing it at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `qw()` is a fancy way of writing an empty list. Doing `()` would be two characters shorter.

Passing an empty list to `use` is important to *avoid* importing. From the [`use` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

> If you do not want to call the package's import method (for instance, to stop your namespace from being altered), explicitly supply the empty list

E.g. by default, the `Cwd` module exports `getcwd`. This doesn't happen if we give it the empty list:

```
use strict;
use Cwd;
print "I am here: ", getcwd, "\n";
```

works, but

```
use strict;
use Cwd ();
print "I am here: ", getcwd, "\n";
```

aborts compilation with `Bareword "getcwd" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that since `qw()` after `use Module` is for importing subroutines, when left empty it simply loads the module but doesn't import any subroutines into the namespace.

For example this throws an error since getcwd is not imported:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd qw();
my $dir=getcwd;
```

But I'm not sure if this is the answer you was looking for..!

Answer (score -2):

Usually it "imports" commands so you don't have to create an object and call the function on them.

Example (from perlmonks):

```
 #without qw
 use CGI;
 my $q = CGI->new();
 my $x = $q->param('x');

 #with qw
 use CGI qw/:standard/;
 my $x = param("x")
```

Source: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1701

Most modules have import groups like :all or :standard also.

Comment: The question is: why explicitly import nothing?

Comment: Force object use on a single instance possibly?

Comment: The answer to the question is given by amon.